# sort list of students by name in c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, alphabetical

I have problem with sorting students by `StudentName` alphabetically.

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
                new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18, Country = "Poland"  } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 22, Country = "Poland"  } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 18, Country = "USA"  } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20, Country = "USA"  } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 21, Country = "Germany"  } 
            };

var listAlphabetically = studentList.OrderBy(x=>x.StudentName);  
            Console.WriteLine(listAlphabetically);
```

Comment: What is the problem? It looks like you're sorting just fine, but you don't know how to output the results?

Comment: What are you expecting to see with `Console.WriteLine(listAlphabetically)`? `Console.WriteLine` on an `object` calls that object's `.ToString()` implementation - which isn't directly helpful with most objects.

Comment: Just change the output to `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", listAlphabetically));`

Comment: What you're really asking is "how do I display a sequence of items in the console?"

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're trying to print the sequence-object `listAlphabetically`  directly to the console using `Console.WriteLine()`.

```
var listAlphabetically = studentList.OrderBy(x => x.StudentName);  
Console.WriteLine(listAlphabetically);
```

`Console.WriteLine()` internally calls the objects `.ToString()`-method. The object gets turned into its `string`-representation which then will be printed to the console. In your case this would probably look like that: `System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable2[StackOverflow.Program+Student,System.String]`.

To overwrite an objects `string`-representation you'll need to define the `.ToString()` method yourself. An example therefore could look like:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"StudentID: {this.StudentID} - StudentName: {this.StudentName} - Age: {this.Age} - Country: {this.Country}";
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to iterate the sequence of `Student`s and print their representation to the console:

```
var listAlphabetically = studentList.OrderBy(x => x.StudentName);

// iterate students and print them to the console
foreach (var student in listAlphabetically)                   
    Console.WriteLine(student);
```

If you only want to print a single property of each student to  the console, you would do something like this:

```
var listAlphabetically = studentList.OrderBy(x => x.StudentName);

// iterate students and print only the ID of each student
foreach (var student in listAlphabetically)                   
    Console.WriteLine(student.StudentID);
```

**Full example**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Student
        {
            public int StudentID { get; set; }
            public string StudentName { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"StudentID: {this.StudentID} - StudentName: {this.StudentName} - Age: {this.Age} - Country: {this.Country}";
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() {
                new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18, Country = "Poland"  } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 22, Country = "Poland"  } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 18, Country = "USA"  } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20, Country = "USA"  } ,
                new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 21, Country = "Germany"  }
            };

            var listAlphabetically = studentList.OrderBy(x => x.StudentName);

            // iterate students and print them to the console
            foreach (var student in listAlphabetically)
                Console.WriteLine(student);

            // keep console open
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

Don't forget to import `System.Collections.Generic` and `System.Linq namespace`, as you will need them to execute the above code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

If not given a string, functions like WriteLine will call `ToString()`. And the default implementation of that is to print the class name. There is no automatic that will print the contents of a Array or Enumerator for you. (And even if there was, the Student class likely did not override `ToString()` either).

If you want to print **array contents**, you have to itterate over it yourself and call the proper properties:

```
foreach(Student current in studentList ){
    Console.WriteLine(current.StudentName);
}
```

Of course in you case, you want to itterate over the enuemrator with the ordering instead:

```
foreach(Student current in listAlphabetically){
    Console.WriteLine(current.StudentName);
}
```

Or use other peoples loops, like with James LINQ Join solution.

Comment: FYI that's not an array.

Comment: @juharr I noticed after writing, it is a enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

[`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1) returns [`IOrderedEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.iorderedenumerable-1?view=netcore-3.1). You have to iterate through it:

```
var listAlphabetically = studentList.OrderBy(x => x.StudentName);

foreach (var student in listAlphabetically)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {student.StudentName}, Age: {student.Age}, Country: {student.Country}");
}
```

Output:

```
Name: Bill, Age: 18, Country: USA
Name: John, Age: 18, Country: Poland
Name: Ram, Age: 20, Country: USA
Name: Ron, Age: 21, Country: Germany
Name: Steve, Age: 22, Country: Poland
```